# Who's the Spanish voice actor for Hratli?

Tags: diablo-ii

This is Hratli, great NPC:

This is Hratli in the Spanish (Spain) translation:

Call me weirdo, but I think this actor's voice is awesome, and I would want to browse a list of his works, at IMDB.

Unluckily, I gave away my game copy and I currently can't go search his name in the translation credits in-game.

Can't find those credits online.

At IMDB, I can find Diablo II, but not the Spanish (Spain) translation.

What else to try? Could you help me at this? :)

Comment: For older voice work, you can sometimes get info from the Wayback machine / voices.fuzzy.com : https://web.archive.org/web/20050204040822/http://voices.fuzzy.com/default.asp ... but they shut it down many years ago.  (for many years, it had better info on voice work than IMDB) ... but in this particular case, they didn't have the spanish actors, either: https://web.archive.org/web/20041224195244/http://voices.fuzzy.com/show.idc?show_id=3879

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hratli is voiced in Spanish by **Enrique Santarén** ([his IMDB entry](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm4079036/) doesn't mention Diablo).

[Here](https://www.doblajevideojuegos.es/fichajuego/diablo-ii/mosaico) is the list of all Spanish voice actors of Diablo II along with their English counterparts.

Comment: It's hard to trace his works, but I know it's common to listen his voice (like, this same calmed temperate tone) in TV documentaries.